# Hadoop mapreduce practice

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

> Input data file:
>
> name,month,category,expenditure

```
hitesh,1,A1,10020  
hitesh,2,A2,10300  
hitesh,3,A3,10400  
hitesh,4,A4,11000  
hitesh,5,A1,21000  
hitesh,6,A2,5000  
hitesh,7,A3,9000  
hitesh,8,A4,1000  
hitesh,9,A1,111000    
hitesh,10,A2,12000  
hitesh,11,A3,71000  
hitesh,12,A4,177000    
kuwar,1,A1,10700  
kuwar,2,A2,17000  
kuwar,3,A3,10070  
kuwar,4,A4,10007
```

Person-wise total spend and count unique categories spent on. (output needs to look like: name, total spend, total count of unique categories)

what i have tried..... my code

Person- Wise total Spend

```
public class Emp   
    {   
     public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>   
     {
      public void map(LongWritable k,Text v, Context con)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
       String line = v.toString();
       String[] w=line.split(",");
       String person=w[0];
       int exp=Integer.parseInt(w[3]);
       con.write(new Text(person), new IntWritable(exp));
      }
     }
     public static class MyRed extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>
     {
      public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<IntWritable> vlist, Context con)
      throws IOException , InterruptedException
      {
       int tot =0;
       for(IntWrit

able v:vlist)
    tot+=v.get();
   con.write(k,new IntWritable(tot));
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
  Configuration c = new Configuration();
  Job j= new Job(c,"person-wise");
  j.setJarByClass(Emp.class);
  j.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
  j.setReducerClass(MyRed.class);
  j.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  j.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  Path p1 = new Path(args[0]);
  Path p2 = new Path(args[1]);
     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(j,p1);
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j,p2);
     System.exit(j.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
 }

}
```

how to get total count of unique categories in this program and how to made output look like name, total spend, total count of unique categories..???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done the modifications in your code. Hope this is useful.

```
 public class Emp   
        {   
         public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>   
         {
          public void map(LongWritable k,Text v, Context con)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException
          {
           String line = v.toString();
           String[] w=line.split(",");
           String person=w[0];
           int exp=Integer.parseInt(w[3]);
           con.write(new Text(person), new Text(line));
          }
         }
         public static class MyRed extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
         {
          public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> vlist, Context con)
          throws IOException , InterruptedException
          {
           int tot =0;
           Set<String> cat = new HashSet<String>();
           for(Text v:vlist){
               String data = v.toString();
               String[] dataArray = data.Split(",");
               tot+ = Integer.parseInt((dataArray[3]); //calculating the total spend
               cat.add(dataArray[2]);// finding the number of unique categories

      }
          con.write(k,new Text(tot.toString()+","+cat.size().toString()));// writing the name,total spend and total unique categories to the output
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
      Configuration c = new Configuration();
      Job j= new Job(c,"person-wise");
      j.setJarByClass(Emp.class);
      j.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
      j.setReducerClass(MyRed.class);
      j.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      j.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      Path p1 = new Path(args[0]);
      Path p2 = new Path(args[1]);
         FileInputFormat.addInputPath(j,p1);
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j,p2);
         System.exit(j.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a custom writable [pair](https://gist.github.com/iceboal/4440822) of IntWritabe and Text one for expenditure and other for category and use that as Map value. Else pass both expenditure and category with some separator in a single string and split that in the reducer side.

Once you get that pair with the same for loop sum up for total expenditure and for category put all the category into a Java Set inside the same for loop, then use set.size() to get number of unique category and print that in context.write. Again when printing the reduce side value you can follow the same technique used to pass map value.

In Mapper side append category and expenditure with a string builder and pass that as the map value.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep=":";
sb.append(w[2]);
sb.append(sep);
sb.append(w[3]);

con.write(new Text(person), new Text(sb.toString()));
```

In the reduce side split the value with what used in the map side and sum up expenditure and calculate the size of the set created with categories. The code is not tested, cast the variables if it is missed in the below code.

```
public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> vlist, Context con)
      throws IOException , InterruptedException
      {
       int tot =0;
       String myval;
       Strng[] split_val;
       Set<String> myset=new HashSet<String>();
       int uniq_category;
       StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
       for(Text v:vlist)
       {
       myval=v.toString();
       split_val=myval.split(":");
       myset.add(split_val[0]);
        tot+=Integer.ParseInt(split_val[1]);
        }
        uniq_category=myset.size();
        String sep="    ";
    sb1.append(uniq_category);
    sb1.append(sep);
    sb1.append(tot);
   con.write(k,new Text(sb1.toString()));
  }
 }
```

Or create a [pair](https://gist.github.com/iceboal/4440822) with IntWritable and Text for map and reduce value as mentioned before.

Comment: @aashish_soni Does that helps in solving your problem?